# ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel-Page and since i want to add a "soft delete" with the *active* field in the DB i get that error:

> *emails.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where (`0` =
>   active and `1` = is active) order by `name` asc)*

-> which causes a error 500 obviously

and I have no plan how to fix this cause it looks like everything is fine.

DB-Layout

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('userID')->nullable();
        $table->string('active', 20)->default('is active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Model:

```
protected $table = 'categories';

protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'image', 'description', 'userID', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Usage(as sample for all other):

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')
            ->where(['active', 'is active'])
            ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

or something like this:

```
->where(['categoryID', $category->id], ['active', 'is active'])
```

Comment: Try changing `->where(['active', 'is active'])` to `->where('active', 'is active')` (without the array brackets)

Comment: thank you that worked but what is when I have something like this _->where(['categoryID', $category->id], ['active', 'is active'])_

Comment: Separate them out into different where's, or use associative arrays, `->where(['categoryID'=> $category->id, 'active' => 'is active'])`

Comment: Or [as they show it in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses), you pass in an array with arrays: `->where( [ ['col1', '=', 'val1'], ['col2', '=', 'val2'] ] )`. Laravels documentation is quite good...

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is causing error.

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->where(['active', 'is active'])
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Eloquent is expecting your where array to be in `key` and `value` pair. As you have not given it, it is using `index` as column name.

You should place it like this:

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->where('active', 'is active') //will also work ->where('active', '=', 'is active')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```